# Can you somehow do WAN for Mirror in Unity without port forwarding?

Tags: unity, c#

Basically i'm using Mirror and it works perfectly when I and my brother wants to play the game I made, but we're on the same network. When my other brother who doesn't live at home can't connect because it only works with LAN. I tried port forwarding but our ISP has locked that it seems. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you walk us through how you're trying to connect now, and how you've configured your port forwarding? This is usually something on your local router, outside your ISP's reach.

Comment: Yeah i know i looked up a tutorial online on port forwarding, and the router won't allow me to do that. It's a router made by our ISP too.

Comment: Then the next thing you need to look into is NAT punch-through. This is where each client attempts to connect to a facilitating server first, which records the IP/port information each one is using and relays it to the other. With this info, they can then attempt a direct connection to each other that the router should regard as a valid outbound connection and reply, rather than an unsolicited inbound connection. [Mirror supports this through its "Fizzy" transport options, according to the documentation](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/transports/fizzysteamworks-transport#features).